# PIL ImageChops.screen in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

How can I write the same code from PIL in OpenCV

```
img3 = ImageChops.screen(im1, im2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement it with the formula used by `ImageChops.screen`:

> out = MAX - ((MAX - image1) * (MAX - image2) / MAX) ([source](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagechops.htm))

The code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

im1 = cv2.imread('im1.png').astype(np.uint16)
im2 = cv2.imread('im2.png').astype(np.uint16)

im3 = (255 - ((255 - im1) * (255 - im2) / 255)).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imwrite('im3.png', im3)
```

The promotion to `uint16`s is necessary because of the multiplication of two `uint18` values, at the end I've casted it back into `uint8`s because the values are guaranteed to be `< 256` again.

Answer (score 0):

> Screen superimposes two inverted images on top of each other ([source](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/Pillow-3.4.1/autoapi/ImageChops/index.html))

you can do this too (without `numpy`):

```
import cv2

# read the input images, they can be color (RGB) images too
im1 = cv2.imread('im1.jpg')
im2 = cv2.imread('im2.jpg')

# images must be of same size, if not resize one of the images 
if im1.shape != im2.shape:
    im2 = cv2.resize(im2, im1.shape[:2][::-1], interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# invert and normalize first image
im1 = cv2.normalize(cv2.bitwise_not(im1), None, 0, 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

# invert and normalize second image
im2 = cv2.normalize(cv2.bitwise_not(im2), None, 0, 1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

# superimpose two images, re-normalize and invert
im = cv2.bitwise_not(cv2.normalize(cv2.multiply(im1, im2), None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U))

# write the output image
cv2.imwrite('im.jpg', im)
```